# how to use different order by clause in each oracle SQL queries in union set operator

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables TEMP1 AND TEMP2 with same number of columns in both the tables.

- Temp1- acct_no varchar2(20), seq number, amount number
- Temp2 -acct_no varchar2(20), seq number, amount number

for instance,
data from temp1 will be like this

temp1

```
acct_no seq amount
200001  1   100
200001  2   50
200001  3   120
200001  4   40
```

temp2

```
acct_no seq amount
200001  1001    100
200001  1002    200
200001  1003    80
200001  1004    90
```

Now my requirement is to fetch data from temp1 and temp2 based on acct_no and data should be like below. I want the data to be first fetched from temp1 by using order by seq descending order and then data to be fetched from temp2 by using order by seq in descending order. Have tried union operator but sort is applied on the final output.

```
seq amount
4   40
3   120
2   50
1   100
1004    90
1003    80
1002    200
1001    100
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two slightly different approaches to this. The first applies the `ORDER BY` to each table in turn, UNION-ing the resulted sorted result sets together:

```
select seq, amount
  from (select *
          from temp1
          order by seq desc)
union all
  select seq, amount
    from (select *
            from temp2
            order by seq desc);
```

The second adds a table identifier to the result set, then orders by the table identifier and `SEQ` so that the output results are ordered as desired:

```
select seq, amount
  from (select t1.*, 1 as table_index
          from temp1 t1
        union all
       select t2.*, 2 as table_index
          from temp2 t2)
order by table_index asc,
         seq desc;
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fb91e176ac0663480cc6f35af0cce3cc)

Answer (score 0):

You should use an explicit `order by` on the entire result set.  So, use `union all` to bring the data together, select the columns that you want, and then use appropriate ordering logic:

```
select seq, amount
from ((select t1.*, 1 as ord
       from temp1 t1
      ) union all
      (select t2.*, 2 as ord
       from temp2 t2
      )
     ) t
order by ord,
         (case when ord = 1 then seq end) desc,
         (case when ord = 2 then seq end) asc;
```

Comment: I think you only need one set of brackets here.